# fscanf for long binary strings in Verilog

Tags: verilog, scanf

I am making a Verilog program that needs to read in lines of 77 bit binary strings from an input file. The input file will be formatted such that it is a string of 77 1's and 0's followed by '\n'.

My program wants to read this line by line and store the entire string into a reg that looks like:

```
reg DATA_REG [76:0]
```

I am using

```
fscanf(data_input_file, "???????", DATA_REG)
```

but I am not sure what to put in the quotations. I want the string to be interpreted literally; that is, if the number is ...0000001110... i want DATA_REG to contain 0000001110, not 1110 or 14.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Never heard of that one! :P so will 

    (for loop until eof)
    readmemb(data_input_file, DATA_REG)

work?

Comment: Hmm, so it seems that this function reads the entire file at once? so I will need to store all the input data at the beginning of the function and then select which line i want each cycle?

Comment: Do you really mean `reg DATA_REG [76:0]`? (An array of 77 single bits). Or do you mean `reg [76:0] DATA_REG`? (A vector of 77 bits, ie a 77 bit number) I haven't tried it, but I doubt `$fscanf` is going to be able to fill up `reg DATA_REG [76:0]` in one go, but it will do `reg [76:0] DATA_REG` in one go. Not only that, "I want DATA_REG to contain 0000001110, not 1110 or 14" doesn't really make any sense: Verilog will store a 77-bit number as just that. It will have leading zeros and whether it is 000...0001110 or 1110 or 14 depends on how your display it.

Answer (score 0):

You have two choices. If the total number of lines to be read is not that large, you can read the entire file into a memory

```
reg [76:0] memory[0:MAX_LINES];
integer index;
initial $readmemb("filename",memory);
always @index DATA_REG = memory[index];// or just use memory[index] directly
```

or you can do

```
status = $fscanf(data_input_file, "%b", DATA_REG);
```

Comment: I notice `DATA_REG` is defined as `reg DATA_REG [76:0]`. Does it not need to be defined as `reg [76:0] DATA_REG` for `status = $fsanf(data_input_file, "%b", DATA_REG);` to work?

Comment: I'm going to assume that was a typo until the OP responds.

Comment: Yes it was a typo. when i try    initial $readmemb("filename",memory);    i get an error "cannot access memory directly"

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the width of the data you are reading as below:

> status = $fscanf(data_input_file, "%**77**b", DATA_REG);

You will need to make sure the data that is there in the input file is of the same width though

Answer (score -1):

you can try this logic it will work.

module TB_example(); reg tb_clk; reg tb_reset; reg one_bit=0;

DW_file DUT_file(.clk (tb_clk ), . reset(tb_reset ), .one_bit(one_bit));

integer fd=0; integer i=0; integer count=0; reg str=0;

initial begin tb_clk=1'b0; forever #20 tb_clk=~tb_clk; end

initial begin tb_reset<=1'b0;/// #2000; tb_reset<=1'b1; #2000; fd = $fopen("sample_1_bit_file.txt", "r"); $display("FILE DATA=%0d",fd);
while (! $feof(fd)) begin @(posedge tb_clk) count<=count+1'b1; $fgets(str, fd); i=$fscanf(fd,"%b",str); one_bit=str; // bit stream of the variable $display("DATA------%0b", str); end $f close(fd); end
endmodule